# Switch from immersion (Activity) to Live Card (Service)

Tags: android, service, android-activity, google-glass, google-gdk

I am launching a High Frequency LiveCard from Service but the Service is actually launch by an activity. I think the LiveCard(Service) has successfully launch but because my activity is still here (immersion) that is why I cant see it, when I swap down to exit the app, it kills the Service.

And now I am confuse. So do I force the app to close after I intent my service? or do I close just the activity? or maybe I should ask, is what I am trying to do even possible?

Activity -> Activity -> ... -> Activity -> Service (maintain LiveCard)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. My problem is my laziness of not reading the document carefully. To show your LiveCard, you WILL HAVE TO SET THE ACTION!! which I was thinking to do that after I get the LiveCard showing. Anyways! HAPPY CODING!

Answer (score 0):

You can call `finish()` inside your activity to dismiss it after you've started your service.

Finishing the activity should not cause the service to stop as well — the service is independent of the activity. Are you sure that your service actually started and did not stop itself at any point (because of an error or some other reason)?

Comment: I tried that but because I actually have multiple layers of activities. It just goes to another activity. I should edit my question.

Comment: I am not getting any kind of error, and that I am assuming I have successfully launch my livecard(service). Is there anyway I can check my service is launch and its running at the background??